# Pass one model from a partial view to a Parent View and bind another model to the same Parent View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, view, model

I have a situation, maybe it has been asked earlier, but I'm not able to get it.

I have a `partial view` namely `_SamplePartial.cshtml`, and a parent view namely `Sample.cshtml`.
Now I want to use the partial view in the parent view, as well as bind the parent view with an another model too.

Below is the code:

```
public ActionResult Sample()
{
 Student student=new Student()
  {
    ID=101,
    Name="Sam",
    City="NY"
  };
 return View(student);
}
```

Sample.cshtml:

```
@model MultipleModels.Models.Student
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sample";
}
<h2>Sample</h2>
@Html.Partial("_SamplePartial",Model)
```

_Samplepartial.cshtml:

```
@model MultipleModels.Models.Student
<table>
    <tr><td>@Model.StudentID</td></tr>
    <tr><td>@Model.StudentName</td></tr>
    <tr><td>@Model.StudentCity</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now I want that another student object be also bound to the View, but it shouldn't come from the Partial View.
For ex:

```
Student stdObj=new Student()
{
ID=999,
Name="Rambo",
City="Sydney"
};
```

The above object should also be present in the View, but it shouldn't be passed as a model from the partial view.

Experts please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer eventually.

Created a ViewModel.

```
public class StudentViewModel()
{
public Student Obj1{get;set;}
public Student Obj2{get;set;}
}
```

In Action Method:

```
public ActionResult Sample()
{
StudentViewModel vm=new StudentViewModel();
vm.Obj1=new Student{ID=101,Name="Sam",City="NY"};
vm.Obj2=new Student{ID=102,Name="Rambo",City="Sydney"};
return View(vm);
}
```

Sample.cshtml:

```
@model MultipleModels.ViewModels.StudentViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sample";
}
<h2>Sample</h2>
<p><b>Directly</b></p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Model.Obj1.StudentID</td>
        <td>@Model.Obj1.StudentName</td>
        <td>@Model.Obj1.StudentCity</td>
    </tr>
</table>
@Html.Partial("_SamplePartial",@Model.Obj2)
```